# running a non-potable exterior water line

Tags: pvc, masonry

I need to run a water line for gardening to a roof deck from the ground level (up 2 floors). I have a courtyard tap, and a brick wall I can run something along the outside of. My thought was to use a splitter on the existing tap, and then run a PVC pipe up the wall and to my deck, anchoring it to the wall.

This isn't for drinking water, it's just for plants on a deck. Any reason not to do it this way? I was just going to get some masonry screws and clamps for the PVC and attach it straight to the brick. Does that create any long-term issues for the brick?

Comment: I did something like this on my last home but forgot to drain the pvc 1 winter. after that I used the black drip irrigation pipe it handled the water in the line much better than the pvc. It is only a 1/2" line but provides plenty of water for all the flowers on the upper deck.

Comment: Don't forget to install an anti siphon and/or check valve as required.  You don't want to contaminate the potable water system.

Comment: @ArchonOSX this should be an answers, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My immediate thought is PVC expands quite a bit. If it is exposed to the sun check to make sure it has room to expand without binding.

Also the UV from the sun will damage the pipe over the years. You may want to paint it or somehow protect it.